# Malformed JSON from API

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest

I'm currently using an API and getting the following results for my GET request:

```
[{"id" : 123456, "title" : "hello world", "post" : "this is the actually text of the    blog"}, {"id" : 123457, "title" : "hello world 2", "post" : "this is the second blog post"}]
```

I want to be able to get each title & post, but my basic knowledge of JSON would tell me that I need to declare each part of the array, like this:

```
["data" : {"id" : 123456, "title" : "hello world", "post" : "this is the actually text of the    blog"}, "data" : {"id" : 123457, "title" : "hello world 2", "post" : "this is the second blog post"}]
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can iterate through this into HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: that's not malformed json. it's an array of objects. decode it, you'll get an array, which contains objects. e.g. `decodedarray[1].id` would be `123457`

Comment: @MarcB, you should add this as an answer.

Comment: Your "basic knowledge of JSON" is wrong. You can only have `"data" : ...` in an object, not an array. And you can't repeat the same `"data":` in the object. You need to go back to your Javascript tutorials and learn the difference between objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is an array containing two objects, the second is an array with a named object, containig two child objects. Your second example won't work, because you're assigning array elements names (data, post) while arrays are auto-indexed with integers. The syntax is simply invalid.

Using the result you get from the API, you first need to convert it into an object.

```
resultObject = JSON.parse('[{"id" : 123456, "title" : "hello world", "post" : "this is the actually text of the    blog"}, {"id" : 123457, "title" : "hello world 2", "post" : "this is the second blog post"}]');
```

After this, you can simply iterate over the array:

```
resultObject.forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e.title + ": " + e.post);
});
```

The above will output

```
hello world: this is the actually text of the    blog
hello world 2: this is the second blog post
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to parse JSON. Use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: You still incorrectly say that the second format is fine. It's not, you can't have property names in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle of the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/4WxFk/3/

```
        <div id="response"></div>
<script>
        var res= '[{"id" : "123456", "title" : "hello world", "post" : "this is the actually text of the blog"}, {"id" : "123457", "title" : "hello world 2", "post" : "this is the second blog post"}]'

        var pres = JSON.parse(res)
        $.each(pres, function(){
            console.log(this)
        $("#response").append(this.id + ","+ this.title + "," + this.post)
        })
</script>
```